# @Autowired doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spock, spring-test

I am trying to create a simple integration test using Spock and Spring. All the necessary dependencies are present in my classpath - spock libs and `spock-spring`. Unfortunately, `underTest` is not being injected (I always get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method someMethod() on null object`). Please see below code

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations=["classpath:test1.xml","classpath:test2.xml"])
class SimpleSpockIntegrationTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    SomeRepo underTest;

    @Transactional
    def "repo test" () {
        expected:
            underTest.someMethod(1) == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a bean definition for SomeRepo type in one of your xml files?

Comment: @lkamal yes - <bean id="someRepo" class="com.stuart.repositories.SomeRepoImpl" autowire-candidate="true"/>

Comment: Let’s do a quick check? Can you add a log or println into SomeRepoImpl constructor to see if an instance is created? Also can you verify that there are no multiple beans from classes that implement SomeRepo interface?

Comment: @lkamal I've already done it. SomeRepo is always null and constructor is not being invoked. Looks like there might be some problems with configuration

Comment: One reason would be multiple implementations of SomeRepo in classpath, have you eliminated that as well?

Comment: Yes, there is only one implementation

Comment: then the simple issue is the xml files are not been picked at runtime. Even though we expect them in root of classpath probably they are not available at that place. Can you try with a fully qualified path?

Comment: Same thing.. I also tried with @Configuration instead of xml file.

Comment: @Stuart Are you sure your Context is getting loaded using that files. Something like @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Comment: @Stuart I think this is related to classpath. Can you check relative paths of your .class files and xml files?

Comment: @lkamal - after switching to Spock 1.0 everything works perfectly.. I was using 1.1. Why?

Comment: So with only Spock version change everything started working? Maybe you can try and open a bug on 1.1

Comment: @lkamal yes. I will do that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there might be a bug in `spock-spring 1.1 (1.1-groovy-2.4)`. After switching to `1.0` (while using `spock-core 1.1`) everything works perfectly.